# running 2 copies of WWW::Mechanize::Firefox in parallel

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, www-mechanize

I'm running strawberry windows perl. I have two copies of firefox portable 
installed with mozrepl.

```
C:\\FirefoxPortable1\\FirefoxPortable.exe'; Using port 4241
C:\\FirefoxPortable2\\FirefoxPortable.exe'; Using port 4242
```

I want to use the two browsers to surf in parallel. I have a good start:

```
use strict;
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore;
use threads::shared;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my @list :shared;
my @browsers :shared;

@list = (10,20); # ,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
@browsers = (1,2); # Array of browsers

my $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new(2);

my @threads;
while (@list != 0) {
  $sem->down; # Request a thread slot, wait if non are available
  my $param1 = shift @list;
  my $param2 = shift @browsers;
  my @params = ($param1, $param2);
  push @threads, threads->create(\&mySubName, @params);
}
$_->join for @threads;

sub mySubName {
  my $id = shift;
  my $browserId = shift;

  print "Running for List Number: $id with browser $browserId.\n";

  my $host = 'C:\\FirefoxPortable'. $browserId .'\\FirefoxPortable.exe';
  my $port = 'localhost:424' . $browserId; 
  my $ff = Firefox::Application->new(
           autodie => 0,
           launch => [$host],
           repl => $port,
           );

  my $mech;
  eval{ $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(
            app => $host,
            repl => $port,
            ); };
  if ($@) {
    undef $mech;
    undef $ff;
    push @list, $id; # on error add the store back into the list
    $sem->up; # Release slot
    return;
  }

  $mech->allow(javascript => 1);

  eval { $mech->get('www.google.com'); };
  if ($@) {
    undef $mech;
    undef $ff;
    push @list, $id; # on error add the store back into the list
    $sem->up; # Release slot
    return;
  }

  #undef $mech;
  #undef $ff;
  push @browsers, $browserId;
  $sem->up # Release slot
}
```

I think I am very close to it. I can get it to work with one. So if you limit the Semaphores to 1 (and change the browser list to just one) it runs just fine. I think my problem has to do with the arguments use when starting up `Firefox::Application` or `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`

The error I got :

```
Thread 2 terminated abnormally: Failed to connect to host localhost port 4242, problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144
```

Let me know if you need any more info. I've spent a lot of time on this and can't figure it out.

Comment: You are [on Windows](http://www.nu42.com/2012/06/using-win32ole-with-events-to-capture.html). Use [Internet Explorer](http://perltricks.com/article/139/2014/12/11/Automated-Internet-Explorer-screenshots-using-Win32--OLE).  Look ma! No semaphores!

Comment: @SinanÜnür Unfortunately using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox is one of the requirements. It's the only module that lets me interact with the site the way I want.

Comment: I feel for you. IE is made to be scriptable. Firefox not so much.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Can you point me at some documentation for what you mean by IE being 'scriptable' or an example of some kind.
EDIT - Sorry, I see now that you did. I'll look into the links in your last post.

Comment: See also [The Internet Explorer Scripting Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970457.aspx)

Comment: Looks like IE isn't going to work. I need to do things like control and modify the cookies of multiple copies of a browser at once. Thanks for the suggestion I'll keep it in mind for future projects.

Comment: I'd use N workers. Each worker would create it's own Mech. The workers would receive requests from a Thread::Queue. Cleaner, and no need to share objects between threads that way. Better design, though it may or may not solve your problem.

Comment: @ikegami's idea would probably work. OTOH, IE does have a private browsing mode (I don't know if that helps you, but it helped me before).

Comment: @ikegami I could use N workers but that doesn't get me any closer to solving my problem which is the interaction between Firefox::Application and WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

Comment: 1. Didn't say it would help. 2. It might actually help depending on what the problem is because you won't be sharing objects between threads anymore

Answer (score 0):

A practical way of achieving you goal would be to instrument the browser using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Kind regards::Rob